# What would happen if a refrigerated bag of human blood was warmed up in a normal kitchen microwave?

Tags: vampires, blood

I have a vampiric character who feeds on human blood. She can do your normal plastic hospital blood bags or from the vein, but obviously blood needs to be refrigerated in order to stay fresh and cold blood is probably pretty unappetizing. I've decided she prefers from the vein because it's quicker and already warm, but what would happen to a microwaved blood bag? I'm aware that (as a snake owner) you don't microwave frozen/thawed mice because they explode. Would the same happen to the blood bag, or something else? How would the blood come out assuming it didn't explode?

(And yes I'm aware putting the bag in warm-hot water would be a valid method of warming it up but let's assume that she doesn't know that for now)

Comment: A Google search indicates that blood bags are often made of PVC and this https://associationofanaesthetists-publications.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1046/j.1365-2044.2000.01319.x says "*The stability of crystalloid solutions heated in a microwave oven has been established, and the release of di‐ethyl pthalate from polyvinyl chloride (PVC) containers has been shown to be minimal, although, to our knowledge, complete screening of all compounds that might leach from PVC bags has not been undertaken.* so microwaving a blood bag shouldn't be toxic or result in an off taste (probably).

Comment: Note some blood bags have metal tubing clips , so they will probably learn to check for that.

Comment: What happens when you warm a steak up in a microwave?

Comment: Surely the vampire would know to put the blood in a bowl and cover it with a plate. This is the equivalent of just shoving a can of soup in the microwave.

Comment: The mice only explode when you overdo it, don't they?

Comment: The blood would coagulate. There's nothing a vampire hates more than coagulated blood. NOTHING!

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica are you sure? Wouldn't it taste like an omelett for them?

Comment: Asking for a f(r)iend?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Ask a Blood Banker:

If we are to assume that the vampire wants the blood to be in something like the native functional state (otherwise the vampire could simply live off of meat), then this is a pretty bad idea.

As a blood banker, I can tell you that the direct exposure of a conventional microwave to blood will cause the spiked heating that will denature the proteins in red cells and also cause lysis (cellular destruction). To a regular person used to cooked food, this might not even be noticeable. To a vampire who needs raw blood, this is like burning dinner.

That being said, certain VERY specific microwaves that heat by air and **not** by bombarding food with microwave radiation are actually used to thaw frozen plasma (the slightly cloudy non-cellular liquid part of blood) - but only in certain places. If your vampire can't freeze blood, don't microwave. The effect of microwaving and freezing is very similar to red cells.

Frozen glycerolized blood (for rare donor type units) uses a different, VERY gentle thawing method, because the individual red cells are extremely fragile and will burst open if mistreated (The glycerol prevents lysis when freezing, and must be washed off and replaced with something like saline). I wouldn't recommend ever heating the blood to a temperature over 37C, or using a water bath for warming more than about 42C.

If the vampire wants to warm it quickly and doesn't mind a little dilution, they can mix their cold (5-10C) blood with warm (about 42C) plasma or saline that approximates the liquid portion of human blood. If you are getting blood from a blood bank, it actually comes to the hospital in a concentrate with part of the liquid portion removed, so diluting with saline would simply bring it up to physiological concentrations (like reconstituting juice).

Comment: If I were a vampire I would send you a 'Thank you' card for this answer ;) . I also want to ask if there is any loss of efficacy or nutritional value after freezing/thawing?

Comment: @Otkin For plasma, freezing works so well they routinely freeze the entire plasma supply. For red cells, there's definitely loss of red cells in the process, and the resulting cells don't last as long as fresh. Still, it leaves open options for vampires in remote locations, on journeys (although thawing is a bit technical) or as emergency storage.

Comment: But does concentrated blood have lower salt content (i.e. does the concentration process remove water *and* salt , or just water?) I'm concerned my wampire might be getting too much salt in their diet if I'm mixing up their smoothie with saline all the time...

Comment: @Caius Jard The concentration process removes plasma, leaving more cells per unit volume. The salt level is the same, so the liquid removed has the same salinity as the liquid added back. For "perfect" blood you'd add plasma to it, but people with low hemoglobin have more fluid in their blood than red cells. Extra/not enough salt would lyse the red cells as well (they're fussy little things).

Comment: "certain VERY specific microwaves that heat by air and not by bombarding food with microwave radiation" – If a machine doesn't use microwave radiation to heat, then surely that means that the machine is not a microwave, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tanner Swett I've only seen one place use them. I believe they heat humid air and circulate it around the units. Everywhere else I've seen uses water baths, but the microwave system was slightly faster. I wanted to make the concession that I have seen microwaves used, but not regular ones.

Comment: Well, my point is that I'm not sure why you're calling those heating machines "microwaves" instead of calling them "ovens" or "heaters." It sounds to me like they're not microwaves. Anyway, I'm just being pedantic.

Comment: @Tanner Swett It is largely a matter of definitions, so that's fine.

Comment: @TannerSwett  I'd guess it uses microwaves to heat the air (or the humidity in the air, more likely) which then heats the blood.

Comment: @Kat Doubtful. Air doesn't really absorb microwaves. Plain old heaters are better. It might be a "convection oven" in a microwave-like form factor (shape)

Comment: @user253751: 1um microwaves won't be absorbed by air, but 100 um is strongly absorbed. As an engineer it means you can choose the absorption length; you can effectively heat the air in the middle of your oven. A convection oven heats the air at the edge, and needs forced circulation to move the hot air around. I can see why you'd want to avoid that in hospital settings.

Answer (score 9):

no probem.

Actually you can microwave frozen mice. You just need to do it right. S L O W L Y . They only explode if you don't give the heat time to dissipate from the more microwave-opaque bits to the rest of the body. It's like boiling an egg in a microwave. Easy, if done right...
The shortcut way is to immerse the object in water, which really soaks up the microwaves. You heat the water which cannot form hotspots because it flows through itself, and in turn the water heats your object.
The non-shortcut is to not be hasty.

blood in bag: ALL a microwave does is jiggle stuff at molecular level, making it hot. The only problem is that some stuff absorbs more, thus heats faster. for a homogenous thing like blood, this should not be a too big problem.
If the container is thick enough, you may need to turn and/or stir it a bit. Or just, be patient. Apply a lower power setting, with longer intervals between active cycles. The heat will dissipate throughout the structure, preventing hotspots.

The only real problem with microwave heating is that it just imparts heat. It does not goal-seek to a certain temperature like convection or conduction heat does. It simply keeps adding heat to whatever part absorbs the most microwaves. This inevitably leads to hotspots, and they can become *very* hot.
The solution is always to just...be...patient.

(Yes, there are some exotic chemical reactions that are favored under microwaves. Some polymerizations for example. This is almost never a real factor, if correct heat control is applied)

You can also get really funky results if the object is very near one wavelength of the microwaves long, or worse yet two objects of 1/2 wavelength with a tiny gap. Google "Microwave Plasma Grape" for some scary stuff!

Comment: There's also the problem that the energy density in the microwave is far from homogeneous.

Comment: @PhilFrost yep. that's why most modern cheap microwaves need a rotating platter, to prevent hotspots. again, only an issue is you try to be fast. Spreading the heating to 10 minutes, instead of 45 seconds, completely voids this problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Let them explode.**

Your character is astonished the first time a bag explodes but very much digs how the inside of the microwave looks after.  She sucks the remaining blood out of the leaky bag and it is way too hot.  She likes that too - hot is good and hotter than a real person is thrilling.  The flavor is intense.   There is steam which sometimes there is from real people when it is cold.  Good memories!

Now she blows up the bag every time and grabs them out as soon as they do.  It makes a mess so she does not wear any clothes - easier to clean up.  Sometimes she licks out the inside of the microwave and the blood from the walls is extra salty.   Mmmm!

This microwaved blood might be better than fresh from a person.

Comment: In the sequel, she decides to microwave people....

Comment: She'd need a big microwave though

Answer (score 3):

Whether the bag would explode depends on;

1. The temperature the contents are heated to; and
2. The strength if the seals on the container i.e. the instructions on some microwave meals tell you to pierce the film to relieve pressure. Other's don't.

Blood bags are made of quite thick material because they have to be tough enough to survive a measure of rough handling during transport and use.

So don't over heat the bag. Firstly because why would you want to? Secondly intense heating with microwaves may well damage the walls and internal structures of blood cells, altering things like lipid structure in the process. Depending on your idea of what vamps need from blood this might well 'ruin the food'.

Best option? Just let it defrost in the fridge overnight then warm it gently to the required temperature in a pot of water on a low heat.

Answer (score 3):

Same as a bag of soup--it's mostly water after all. So long as your vampire uses the same precautions as a normal person heating something that's mostly water, like: no metal containers, holes in sealed bags to vent steam etc., she should be fine.

The major difference is in whether vampires need living blood. Blood bags consist of living cells for transfusion into living recipients. Soup does not. Microwaves or any other form of high heat will kill cells

Comment: Would you say that eggs are mostly water too? Because when you microwave eggs, they coagulate, and I believe same would happen with blood (and wouldn't with soup)

Comment: @Rafalon: Having actually boiled eggs in a microwave: they don't coagulate entirely. Heating a raw egg for two minutes: the parts in contact with the container turn white and pitted with bubbles; the centre with the yolk changes texture, which is apparent when shaken, but no visible change. Now, repeating the experiment with salt scattered over the raw egg, results in white spots appearing after 30s around the location of the salt grains